# Why does javascript not execute this block properly in this situation?

Tags: javascript, block, execution

The function below was used in two .php documents. This code works perfectly in the first but in the second document it only executes the first two assignment statements in the (mode=="on") condition.

In the first document "popoutfg" is an iframe found in the parent window.
In the 2nd document "popoutfg" is an iframe found within another iframe located in the parent window.

So basically the problem is in the 2nd one it only executes these two:  `temp1.style.visibility="visible";` and
`temp2.style.visibility="visible";` .

***Please and thank you! =3***

```
function popout(mode, links, width, height, paddingh, paddingv)  
{
    var temp1 = document.getElementById("popoutfg");  
    var temp2 = document.getElementById("popoutbg");  
    if(mode == "on")
    {  
        temp1.style.visibility = "visible";  
        temp2.style.visibility = "visible";  
        temp1.style.width = width;  
        temp1.style.height = height;  
        temp1.style.left = paddingh;  
        temp1.style.right = paddingh;  
        temp1.style.top = paddingv;  
        temp1.style.bottom = paddingv;  
        temp1.src = links;  
    }  

    if(mode == "off")  
    {
        temp1.style.visibility = "hidden";  
        temp2.style.visibility = "hidden";  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Then, you probably have a javascript error.  Did you look in the error console or the debugger console to see what it says?  Are you absolutely sure that temp1 and temp2 are valid?  What is the `>` character doing on this line: `>temp1.style.visibility="visible";`?

Comment: I would not expect `document.getElementById()` to work when called from a parent page to find an element within an iframe on the parent page. Are you sure that part is working? (What do you get if before the `if` you throw in an `alert(temp1.id);`?)

Comment: @jfriend - oh sorry, the > was an mistype i did while copying the code. I got confused with stackoverflows way of inputting things.

Well im sure that temp1 is vailid since it does change the iframes visibility into visible it just doesnt set the rest of the style attributes.

Comment: @nnnnnn

the document.getElementById is called from the iframe (im trying to ues the fact the variables are locally declared)

the alert(temop1.id); returns a "popoutfg". =3

Comment: So ... did you look for javascript errors like I asked earlier?  Do you know how to step through the code line by line in a debugger like Firebug in Firefox or the built-in Chrome debugger.

Comment: @jfriend00
No, im not familiar with those. I'm using the IE version of server2go so i can run my php scripts locally. I'm not familiar with browser debuggers sorry.

Ill try and delve into those. Thanks for the suggestion xD

Comment: A browser debugger is pretty easy to pick up and will save you immense amounts of time.  I suggest Chrome with it's built-in debugger.  You just right-click on any web page and select "Inspect Element" and a whole new world opens up for you.

Comment: Hey i just tested out the ie debugger and it did give me an error.  
Line: 11  
Error: Invalid argument.  

So thats this one . "temp1.style.width=width;"
But thats odd. It worked on the other php.

And i didnt know the inspect element was a debugger haha thatll be useful xD

Comment: Just a side note, but you really should use `equals()` when comparing strings (i.e. `if (mode.equals("on"))` instead of `if (mode == "on")`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
alert(width);
```

before

```
temp1.style.width = width;
```

*Invalid Argument* error suggests that you are not setting the width parameter legitimately. If this doesn't help let me know the value you saw in alert and we will try to further investigate.